# How to get NFT trade information in on-chain Exchange

Tags: ethereum, nft, opensea

Recently, I wanted to track the price of NFT on global markets such as blur and opensea, so I looked in several NFT API providers (3rd party APIs such as : SimpleHash(https://simplehash.com/), Alchemy(https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/getnfts)), but in the end, I realized that the APIs provided are unstable.
For example, the data is not reflected in real-time, A lot of transaction data was missing.
Therefore, if possible, I would like to attach myself to the node and find the sale information, but is it possible to find on-chain exchange Sales data? and if I can, Can you explain to me how to do that?

The reason why I thought it was difficult is that first of all, I need to know the smart contract of every exchange, and then I need to keep track of the smart contract updates.

Comment: Why do you need it on chain, most of the time you would just reflect the price on the frontend, and then use that value when calling on chain.   If you really need it on chain you can either query the smartcontract and create an order book, or you can use an oracle.